# Hide link in rails based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have an Opportunity and a User model. A User can log in as an admin (I have admin as a boolean attribute). I want users to be able to delete opportunities if and only if they are an admin and I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to do this? So far I have the following delete link for my opportunity:

views/opportunities_opportunity
    
       <%= link_to_if(@user.admin?, "Delete", opportunity, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}) %>

However, I keep getting the error "undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass"

Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: could you add User model so we can see how admin is set up ?

Comment: Your error is saying your `@user` object is nil.  How are you defining your `@user` object in your controller?

Comment: are you referring to my user or object controller? @ChrisBarthol

Comment: apologies I meant app/models/user.rb

Comment: actually, i fixed it.. i used @current_user.admin? instead of @user.admin

Comment: Do you have an opportunities controller?  Where are you defining the `@user` instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

fixed... I use @current_user.admin? instead and it worked.

Comment: Felipe, he's answering his own question